# Request file from web api and play it on client side?

Tags: java, rest, web-services, filesystems, web-frontend

Hello :) This is more of an architectural question than code, so I'm sorry if I'm in wrong place.
I have a java webapi developed in spring boot and another component that is a normal webapp based on html, css and javascript. 
In the webapi server I have some files stored in the filesystem, mostly are images (.png), videos (.mp4) and presentations (.pdf). 
I'm setting up a html page in the webapp and a script that already receives the files metadata and show some of that data to the user. After user selects the content he wants to see, the webapp should make a GET request to the webapi endpoint and the webapi should get the requested file, send it back to the client in success response and the client should play the received file on the browser.
I already searched a lot but I don't find any talk about this, the only examples I get is about downloading files or getting the files directly in the webapp without passing by the webapi.

I have already tried to play a video file by trying src="urlFromWebApi/filesystemfilepath/filename" but it displays 403 error (I don't why I even tried this, already know it wouldn't work).

This is just my ajax call to get the files metadata ordered by upload date. It works good and it loads the files metadata to the page.

function searchDefault(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8888/search/date",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data)
            loadResultsToPage(data);
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#tableColumnsLine").html('\n' +
                '                ×\n' +
                '            **Failed to search! Please try again**' +
                '            ');
        }
    });
}

On files metadata click the content of the file should be presented to the user. E.g. if the user selects a title of a video file, the browser should display the video and start playing it.